# Phonegap: Globalization: How to redirect to .html page in this function?

Tags: javascript, cordova, localization, globalization

I've got this function to alert the preferred language on the device:

```
function checkLanguage() {
  navigator.globalization.getPreferredLanguage(
    function (language) {alert('language: ' + language.value + '\n');},
    function () {alert('Error getting language\n');}
  );
}
```

it returns for example: "Deutsch" .. or.. "English"

I want to redirect to a .html document if the value is e.g "English"

I tried this:

```
function checkLanguage() {
  navigator.globalization.getPreferredLanguage(
    function (language) {
    if(language.value == English) {window.location = "NewDocument.html"; } }
    function () {alert('Error getting language\n');}
  );
}
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: Try if(language.value == "English")

Comment: didn´t work either... but thanks for the reply

Comment: So, what is the error ? It's the redirection ? Try window.location.replace("NewDocument.html")

Comment: In the case when the browser is set to the en_US locale, this should display a popup dialog with the text "language: English".... Does that mean i have to use the en_US? But doesn´t work either..

Comment: The error is, nothing happens when i call the function and no redirect takes place

Answer (score 1):

There are some syntax error. Try this :

```
function checkLanguage() {
   navigator.globalization.getPreferredLanguage(
       function (language)
       {
           if(language.value == "English")
           {
               window.location.replace("NewDocument.html");
           }
       },
       function ()
       {
           alert('Error getting language\n');
       }
   );
}
```

Comment: where can I get the list of all the languages (strings)